# How can I use Dapper in a multi database environment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, dapper

I'm trying to implement simple queries like `SELECT * FROM TABLE_X WHERE XID = @id`, but the problem that I'm having is that these queries would run on different databases (SQL Server and Oracle) for different application instances.

How to do it without to have to write each database a new set of queries?

Answer (score 2):

Dapper is really close to the database, and allow you to leverage pure SQL tricks specific for a specific database. In my opinion you should use a query object pattern, so you will have an interface in front of each extraction /commit that would possibly change for SQL/Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded the code of `SqlMapper.cs` and hacked `SetupCommand` to check if the command is from Oracle or SQL Server.

That was what I did:

```cs
if (cnn.GetType().Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("oracle"))
{
    sql = sql.Replace('@', ':');
}
```